Non-strictly unital functors of infinity categories?
One potential limitation of the quasicategory model of $(\infty,1)$-categories seems to be that the identity morphisms are "a part of the structure" of each quasicategory, and that morphisms of quasicategories preserve said structure. In other words, all morphisms of quasicategories are "strictly unital", in the appropriate sense.
My broad question (intentionally stated to be rather vague) is as follows: Do we "miss anything meaningful" by only considering the strictly unital maps of $(\infty,1)$-categories?
More concretely, I am wondering:

Is there a known way to recover these desired "non-strictly unital" morphisms of $(\infty,1)$-categories using the quasicategory model?
Is there an $\infty$-cosmos which is weakly equivalent to the $\infty$-cosmos of quasicategories (using the language of "Infinity category theory from scratch") and contains these desired "non-strictly unital" morphisms of $(\infty,1)$-categories? If so, does this establish the answer of "no" to my broad question?

A potential solution to 1. that I have seen is as follows:
Hiro Lee Tanaka's paper "Functors (between $\infty$-categories) that aren't strictly unital" discusses the possibility that non-strictly unital maps of $(\infty,1)$-categories $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ can be identified as maps of the corresponding underlying semi-simplicial sets $\mathcal{C}_{\text{inj}}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}_{\text{inj}}$ where the image of the  degenerate edges of $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathcal{C}_{\text{inj}}$ are sent to edges of $\mathcal{D}_{\text{inj}}$ which correspond to isomorphisms in $\mathcal{D}$. Such morphisms naturally form the vertices of an $(\infty,1)$-category which is canonically equivalent to $\text{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$. I've included the construction of said $(\infty,1)$-category and said equivalence here for convenience: The restriction map $\text{Set}_\Delta\rightarrow \text{sSet}_\Delta$, $\mathcal{C}\rightsquigarrow \mathcal{C}_{\text{inj}}$ admits a left adjoint, $\mathcal{C}\rightsquigarrow \mathcal{C}_+$. Here, $\mathcal{C}_+$ naturally contains a collection of non-degenerate which are identified with the set of degenerate edges of $\mathcal{C}$, call these $s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)$, and the vertices of $\mathcal{C}_+$ agree with the vertices of $\mathcal{C}$. Theorem 1.1 extablishes that the counit map $\mathcal{C}_+\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ exhibits $\mathcal{C}$ as a localization of $\mathcal{C}_+$ with respect to $s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)$ (in the definition of Kerodon 01MP), and so for all $(\infty,1)$-categories $\mathcal{D}$, the natural functor $\text{Fun}(\mathcal{C}_+[s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)^{-1}],\mathcal{D})\rightarrow \text{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ is an equivalence of $(\infty,1)$-categories. Tanaka's paper also establishes that any arrow $F\in \text{Fun}(\mathcal{C}_+[s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)^{-1}],\mathcal{D})$ sends each edge in $s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)$ to an isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}$ which is homotopic to the relevant identity morphism (Remark 3.2).
This certainly seems promising, but in considering maps $F\in \text{Fun}(\mathcal{C}_+[s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)^{-1}],\mathcal{D})$ as our "non-strictly unital maps of $(\infty,1)$-categories", it seems to me that we are even missing the desired compatibility of the implied homotopies $\text{id}_{F(X)}\implies F(\text{id}_X)$ with our 2-morphisms (for example, see the nLab page for pseudo-functors). It also seems that the same issues arise for natural transformations between pairs of maps $F,G\in \text{Fun}(\mathcal{C}_+[s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)^{-1}],\mathcal{D})$ which do happen to satisfy our desired compatibility constraints. Perhaps there is a good way to choose a subcategory of $\text{Fun}(\mathcal{C}_+[s_0(\mathcal{C}_0)^{-1}],\mathcal{D})$ whose vertices and edges meet all of our said compatibility constraints?
Thank you very much in advance, and sorry if this question is too long/needs editing (this is my first MathOverflow question, so please bear with me!)

Of potential relevance is Yonatan Harpaz's thesis on quasi-unital $\infty$-categories

@MaximeRamzi Thanks! I will check this out.
